# How do I create an Environment variable in windows using Powershell that's accessible in a WebApi app?

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-web-api, environment-variables

How do I create an Environment variable in windows using Powershell that can then be accessed in an WebApi application using the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()` method?

Here is what I've tried:

I created a powershell script called SetEnvironment.ps1. The contents of the file are:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TEST', 'testval')
```

then I ran the script using this command:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File .\SetEnvironment.ps1
```

Upon checking using `$Env:TEST` command, I found that environment path does not get saved.

If I add that command (`$Env:TEST`) within the script itself it works. But outside of that it doesn't work.

I've also tried killing explorer.exe and restarting it. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: It looks like there's an overload that takes a `target` parameter to set the variable for the machine or user: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is the output of `echo [Environment]::UserName` from your script, and does it match the username in your powershell window?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser How do I check my powershell window's user? I'm running the powershell window as an Admin

Comment: I just meant running `echo [Environment]::UserName` in both and comparing them. The `powershell` command might be using a standard user instead of your admin, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting an environment variable only for the PowerShell process. You need to set one globally.

Use [`EnvironmentVariableTarget`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the access you need

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('TEST', 'testval', [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Alternatively, if you create a process from PowerShell, that process will inherit any environment variables you might set. Do this if you can, as I generally discourage setting global environment variables.

Comment: Thank you. I had actually tried a different variation of that (just passed 'Machine' as string).

But I tried your method and it kind of worked. When I close the existing powershell and reopen it (as an Admin), it works. I'm able to see the TEST environment variable. 

But I can't see it in any other powershell window and I am not able to retrieve it from the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST") method in c#. 

Any ideas?

Comment: @Shaz If you set the environment variable when the other process was already opened, then it won't be updated. When a new process is created, it inherits its own copy of environment variables (if this didn't happen, think of the mayhem that would ensue if two processes tried to write to a variable at the same time). You can't change the variables of another process, only your own. You need to close and restart the program for it to get the new value.

Comment: THANKS!! It worked. When I opened a new process it worked. And in the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable method I had to use the overload which allowed me to specify the EnvironmentVariableTarget